# Class not Found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

Trying to print `books` database content and I receive the following error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at jdbc.JDBCConnector.main(JDBCConnector.java:22)
The end!
```

What was done:

- mysql-connector jar file has been added already. [image: Screenshot from Eclipse]
- I've also tried different versions to import: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39` and `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8`
- I tried to use both: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/books` as well as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books` as the database URL

I would be really glad if someone could help me to clarify this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added the `zip` into your `classpath` instead of the `jar` that is the reason why, put only `mysql-connection-java-4.1.39-bin.jar` into your `classpath`.